# Could not initialize class android.databinding.parser.XMLLexer

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

After enabling Android DataBinding, I kept getting this error message:

```
Could not initialize class android.databinding.parser.XMLLexer

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseOriginalXml(LayoutFileParser.java:130)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:93)
    at ...
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuntimeMetaData$VersionMismatchException: ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.3
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuntimeMetaData.checkVersion(RuntimeMetaData.java:397)
    at android.databinding.parser.XMLLexer.<clinit>(XMLLexer.java:14)
    ... 102 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the same boat, check to see if you have any other dependencies using ANTLR. In my case, a java module had a dependency on an outdated `com.github.jknack:handlebars:2.0.0`. Updating the dependency to the latest version finally fixed my issue.

If this doesn't fix your issue, try checking to see if you still have the old databinding plugin enabled, and remove it if you do. All you should need to enable databinding is the latest Android gradle plugin and:

```
android {
    ...

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

in every Android module.